# Images taken from camera roll take long time to display in uitableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using this class to take images from a `UIImagePickerController/Camera`, store them in the documents directory and display them to the user.  Essentially this codes works, however it takes a very long time to actually display the data in the UITableView after the user selects an image (10+ seconds at least).

Here is my class (not the full class, just the problem code):

```
#import "ReceiptImageViewController.h"
#import "ReceiptImageCell.h"

@interface ReceiptImageViewController ()

@end

@implementation ReceiptImageViewController

@synthesize fields;
@synthesize receiptNumber;
@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //Set UI Colors
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.navigationController.toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"ViewDidAppear");
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"Table Data Reloaded");
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    [images removeAllObjects];
    for (NSString *path in fields)
    {
        if (![path isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
            [images addObject:image];
            NSLog(@"Adding Image");
        }
        NSLog(@"Loop");
    }
    return [images count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ReceiptImageCell";
    ReceiptImageCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    //Set info label text
    cell.infoLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Receipt Image: %d", indexPath.row];
    cell.receiptImage.image = [images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UIActionSheet Delegate

//Displays action sheet when the user presses
//'+' button next to image view
-(IBAction)showActionSheet:(id)sender{

    UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Receipt Image" 
                                                            delegate:self 
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              destructiveButtonTitle:NULL 
                                                   otherButtonTitles:@"Take Picture", @"Choose From Library", nil];
    popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
    popupQuery.tag = 0;
    [popupQuery showInView:self.view];

    //    //FOR TESTING ON SIMULATOR 
//    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Receipt1.jpg"];
//    int i = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] + 1;
//    NSString* imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Receipt%@Image%d", receiptNumber, i];
//    [self saveImage:image :imageName];
}

//Saves receipt image to documents directory
- (void)saveImage:(UIImage*)image:(NSString*)imageName 
{ 
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); //convert image into .png format.

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];//create instance of NSFileManager

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //create an array and store result of our search for the documents directory in it

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //create NSString object, that holds our exact path to the documents directory

    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", imageName]]; //add our image to the path 

    [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil]; //finally save the path (image)

    [fields addObject:fullPath];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    NSLog(@"image saved");
}

#pragma mark - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

//Receive the image the user picks from the image picker controller
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info {
    // Do stuff to image.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        UIImage* image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        int i = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] + 1;
        NSString* imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Receipt%@Image%d", receiptNumber, i];
        [self saveImage:image :imageName];
    });

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (actionSheet.tag == 0){
        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            NSLog(@"Take Picture Button Clicked");
            // Create image picker controller
            UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

            // Set source to the camera
            imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

            // Delegate is self
            imagePicker.delegate = self;

            // Show image picker
            [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
        } 
        else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            NSLog(@"Choose From Library Button Clicked");
            // Create image picker controller
            UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

            // Set source to the camera
            imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

            // Delegate is self
            imagePicker.delegate = self;

            // Show image picker
            [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
        } 
        else if (buttonIndex == 2) {
            NSLog(@"Cancel Button Clicked");
        } 
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why this happens?  I've run into this problem in other applications and have never managed to find a solution..Even one that involves using activity indicators or similar?

Thanks a lot,

Jack

Comment: Look at your tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: implementation. Every time this method is called, you're releasing all images (by removeAllObjects) and you're reading them again SYNCHRONOUSLY. Also you do use full sized images in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: Do you need full sized images? If not, scale them down before saving to documents. Why do you save them to documents directory? You can store URL to asset and save some space on device, ...

Comment: It makes sense that it takes a long time to display information if you're scaling down a bunch of photos and loading them every time the user clicks something. And, as Robert noted, why are you calling `removeAllObjects`? That just multiplies the inefficiency.